# Vertical alignment is different on iOs Safari than Chrome web browser

Tags: css

Can anybody please shed explain why the overlay div with my name in white writing is not aligning in the centre on my mobile? https://anthonymarshall.design/ It's difficult to fix as it appears in the centre in chrome dev tools set to iPhone.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.